# About AJAX , FORM AND PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My ajax code looks like this which check the registration form username, email, etc...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#formform").on('change', 'input',function(event){
    var $form = $(this);
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    request = $.ajax({
        url: "/registration_check.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {formData:serializedData},
        datetype: "JSON"
    });
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log(response);
    });
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log("error");
    });
    request.always(function () {
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

And my PHP look like this:

```
$get_form_data=$_POST["formData"];
parse_str($get_form_data,$form_data);

if(isset($form_data["username"])){
    if(strlen($form_data["username"])<5){
        echo "Username must be at least 5 character";
    }else{
        if(ValidUserName($form_data["username"])){
            if($checkUser->checkUserName(char_encoder($form_data["username"]))==true){
                echo "Sorry this UserName Already Exist";
            }else{
                echo "UserName Available";
            };
        }else{
            echo "Invalid Username";
        }

    }

}
```

Now How do i disable the form when Invalid Username comes from AJAX as response?

I though i should use return false..but don't know how to handle the response?

Comment: You have `$inputs.prop("disabled", false);` which will always ENABLE your fields after response.

Comment: Check "data" , in Ajax response , `if (data == "Invalid Username"){event.preventDefault();}`

Comment: Pratik it is just php sample for Invalid username there are more things like INvalid EMail , Invalid Password , Invalid  Details and bla bla bla :( things getts more complicated isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try as below format you can handle response in success event:

```
var $form = $(this);
var serializedData = $form.serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/registration_check.php",
    data: {
        formData:serializedData
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        //do stuff like loading process until you get the response
    },
    success: function (resp) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(resp);
        //console.log(obj); // this will display response in console.
        //do stuff here

    },
    error: function(e){
        alert("Error in ajax call: "+e);
    } 

}); // complete AJAX
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
$array = array();
if (isset($form_data["username"])) {
    if (strlen($form_data["username"]) < 5) {
        $array['success'] = false;
        $array['message'] = "Username must be at least 5 character";
    } else {
        if (ValidUserName($form_data["username"])) {
            if ($checkUser->checkUserName(char_encoder($form_data["username"])) == true) {
                $array['success'] = false;
                $array['message'] = "Sorry this UserName Already Exist";
            } else {
                $array['success'] = true;
                $array['message'] = "UserName Available";
            }
        } else {
            $array['success'] = false;
            $array['message'] = "Invalid Username";
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

Comment: How do i disable form when php send invalid username , invalid email etc .. :(

Comment: You can handle that in success callback function like once you get invalid email in success callback you can empty that textbox and display message which you get from php file in json object.

Comment: Yes man...Really thanks..solved my problem very cleanly ..You are great :)

Answer (score 0):

make your ajax call on form submit event and call `event.preventDefault();` if ajax returns any error.
Hope this help :)